# Flash message showing up again on clicking the back button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

I am using `flash` hash to render prompts to user. It also contains a font-awesome icon so it renders something like this:

[image]

So the flash message renders properly but the issue is if I visit any other link on a page and then click the back button, it re-renders the flash message again.

Here's the logic behind rendering the flash message:

In `application_controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  add_flash_types :success, :notice
end
```

In `sessions_controller`:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(its: params[:sessions][:its])
    if user&.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id

      respond_to do |format|
        format.all { redirect_to root_path(format: :html), success: t(".success") }
      end
    else
      flash.now.alert = t(".error")
      render :new, status: :not_found
    end
  end
```

In partial `flash_messages`:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <div id="flash" data-controller="autohide">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= render_flash_message(name, msg) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`render_flash_message` helper method:

```
  def render_flash_message(type, msg)
    content_tag :div, id: "flash-#{type}" do
      concat(content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa-circle-check"))
      concat(content_tag(:span, " #{msg}"))
    end
  end
```

I found some stack-overflow posts related to this:

1. [flash[:notice] is shown on browser back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370392/flashnotice-is-shown-on-browser-back-again)
2. [Flash Message Stays After Leaving The Page And Returning Multiple Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199018/rails-4-flash-message-stays-after-leaving-the-page-and-returning-multiple-time)
3. [How to show the flash message in Rails only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142527/how-to-show-the-flash-message-in-rails-only-once)

So as suggested by those answers, I have tried these:

1. Use `discard` method.

```
  respond_to do |format|
    flash.discard[:success] = t(".success")
    format.all { redirect_to root_path(format: :html) }
  end
```

**Result: Same behavior**

2. `<% flash[name]=nil %>` in my `_flash_messages.html.erb`

```
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= render_flash_message(name, msg) %>
      <% flash[name]=nil %>
    <% end %>
```

**Result: Ends up rendering new flash message with `nil` value and renders it on visiting next page**

3. Disabling Cache in `application_controller.rb`:

```
  before_action :set_cache_buster

  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

**Result: This works but it expires all caches set in the application, resulting in more SQL queries**

So the only solution that did work was setting cache to nil but that isn't something that I am looking for, so can anyone suggest any other solutions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but you can try flash.now[:success] = "..." (see https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now)

Comment: The page redirects after successfully authenticating the user so using `flash.now` won't even render on the page because `flash.now` is meant to be used for `render`ing the same page on unuccessfully authenticating the user.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `data-turbo-temporary` attribute to the `flash` block removes the element before the document is cached, preventing it from reappearing.

```html
  <div id="flash" data-controller="autohide" data-turbo-temporary>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= render_flash_message(name, msg) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

[Source](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes)